# timestamp from year and day of year?

Tags: python, date, timestamp

I have to deduce the timestamp number from a list of items in Python 2.7.

For each item I have the year and the days of the year when it was created, for example:

```
year = 2015
days = 154
```

I don't have any data about hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds, so I assume that they are all equal to `0`.

Can someone help me to deduce a timestamp?

Comment: With only year and week, you can't know the exact day, so you can't get a timestamp. You need at least the day of the week, and also the time (hour/minute/seconds) to get the timestamp (or you assume that the time will be zero, but anyway you need to define how to handle the missing fields).

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "week" (and what time during that 7 day period you want). There are different interpretations. See Wikipedia article about [**Week numbering**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Week_numbering).

Comment: Is possible to have a timestamp with the year and the days of that year?
For example:
   year = 2015
   day = 154

Comment: Even if you have the day, you still need the hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds to get the timestamp (or you can assume they're all zero, but you still need those fields defined).

Comment: if i assume that the hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds are zero?

Comment: If you set to zero, then yes, it's possible. If that's what you want, please [edit] the question with those information, so people can answer accordingly.

Comment: i have edit it, now i hope that is more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving a **year** and a **day of the year**, you can have a date with day, month and year. But to get a timestamp, you still need the hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds and a timezone.

In the example below, I'm setting the time fields (hour/minute/seconds/millisecond) to zero and timezone to UTC:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

year = 2017
day_of_year = 154
# strptime sets the hours/minutes/secs to zero
d = datetime.strptime("%s %s" % (year, day_of_year), "%Y %j").replace(tzinfo = pytz.utc)
print(d.timestamp())
print(d)
```

The date `d` will be `2017-06-03 00:00:00+00:00` and the respective timestamp will be `1496448000` - the number of **seconds** from unix epoch (`1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`). If you want the timestamp in **milliseconds**, just multiply this value by 1000.

Although I used **UTC**, you can change it to use the timezone that suits best for your case.

Comment: @user3466686 You're welcome. If you found this answer helpful and it solved your problem, you can accept it and/or upvote it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers